# Get back record mistakenly updated due to subquery wrong alias name

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I was about to execute below update query -

```
update t1 set t1.a=(select distinct t2.a from t2 where t1.id=t2.id and rownumber=1) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t1.id= t2.id and  T1.email='test@dummymail.com' )
```

But, I have mistakenly executed below query **with subquery also including t1**. Now, I am affraid that records has been updated wrong.

`update t1 set t1.a=(select distinct t2.a from t2,t1 where t1.id=t2.id and rownumber=1) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t1.id= t2.id and  T1.email='test@dummymail.com' )`

Now I am trying to find out records which got updated due to wrong update query.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please only tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Any answer, here is completely dependant on the RDBMS too, so we really need to know what it is.

Comment: Why not just run the correct update statement which would fix the previous incorrect values?

Comment: I know it is, @NadeemShaikh . The comment was aimed at another that has since been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should assume that all rows were updated with the wrong value and just re-run the update:

```
update t1
    set t1.a = (select t2.a
                from t2
                where t1.id = t2.id and t2.rownumber = 1
               );
```

You didn't change the value of `id` or `rownumber`, so I think this will be fine.

Note that the `select distinct` is useless in the subquery.  Presumably, `rownumber = 1` is only selecting one row (if not, you are using a very poor naming convention).

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, I have updated query. sorry I forgot to mention about one where condition used in it.

Comment: @NadeemShaikh . . . This answers the question that you asked originally.  I don't play games of "what should the question really be".  That said, if you add a `where` clause to the `update` it will probably do what you want.